# How to update User Role in Rails 5 + Cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rolify

I am stuck in User role. I am using Cancancan with devise gem. 
How to update user role without removing a role from the table.

I am using like this but this is not work

Roles Stored in DB user_roles and Role Master

```
 USERROLES = ["subscriber","user","moderator", "admin" ,"superadmin"].freeze # static for find value without call Role master

  def change_role
    if current_user.has_role?(:superadmin)
      @user_id = params[:id]
      if !params[:r_id].blank? && !params[:id].blank?
        @role_id = params[:r_id].to_i == 5 ? 4 : params[:role_id].to_i
        user = User.find(@user_id)
        user.remove_role user.roles.first.name
        user.add_role USERROLES[@role_id]
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I would take a look at existing solutions like Rolify before trying to roll your own. I would say that this attempt is very naive and quite flawed.

Comment: so how can I update my existing user roles?

Comment: like wordpress admin can change user roles

Comment: How is the user role saved in the user model? But overall this looks risky, if you ever add or remove a role from the array, the ids will change. So it would be better to use a hash.

Comment: i think you make mistake... I am not removing roles from an array. Array is just for find name it just a static value. I use rolify with cancancan and storing roles into the user_roles table while I remove some role from my functionality (remove_role). it automatically deleted from role master table. i can't find any role update method. finally i am using Raw query to update user_roles